# Materialize CSS and Angular 4 Initialize not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, materialize

I have a sidenav and a select-tag from Materialize CSS in my Angular 4 App. They both work when you refresh the page on the page where the sidenav and select-tag are defined. To clarify, I use a select-tag on my register page (route = /register). When I start the app, I get directed to /login, if I then go to /register, the select tag is not shown. When I refresh the page, I can see the select tag.

I initialize my tags in index.html as follow:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    (function ($) {
      $(function () {

        $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
          edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
          closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
        });

      }); // end of document ready
    })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
  </script>
```

This code works but only when I refresh the page where the tags are used. How can I solve this annoying problem?

Comment: did u find how to fix it ? I have the same problem as you and I can't solve it yet. :(

Comment: @MahaloBankupu I added the code into the Angular ngAfterViewInit() function and added after the imports "declare var $: any;" It's not the most beautiful fix, but it works for me now